# how to use timestamp in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i use this but it having some error

> CREATE TABLE notifications (   id int,   postdate timestamp NULL
>   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   descriptions varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
>   notitype varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (id) )

Comment: Is it MySQL or MS SQL Server? They're different products...

Comment: It's "having some error", as in, some ambiguously nebulously ambiguous "error", and not some more specifically identifiable error? Because both MySQL and SQL Server are pretty good at issuing *identifiable* errors. (Though it is arguable that the prevalent MySQL "Error #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax" can be a little unhelpful in identifying what the syntax error actually is.)

Comment: the timestamp datatype is deprecated. It also is NOT a datatype that holds datetime information. If you want datetime data use the datetime datatype. Here is the reference to timestamp. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one plz

> CREATE TABLE notifications ( id int, postdate DATETIME NULL DEFAULT
>   GETUTCDATE(), descriptions varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, notitype
>   varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)  )

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
postdate timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

to

```
postdate DATETIME NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
```

---

I thought you are using MS SQL, aren't you? Your tags were asp.net and so on. Now you checked mysql, are you sure you need mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html#1_4)

```
CREATE TABLE example_timestamp (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
data VARCHAR(100),
cur_timestamp TIMESTAMP(8)

 +----+--------------------------+---------------------+
 | id | data                     | cur_timestamp       |
 +----+--------------------------+---------------------+
 |  1 | The time of creation is: | 2004-12-01 20:37:22 |
 +----+--------------------------+---------------------+
```